# Answer deleted & converted to a comment. Should it link to the comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-answers, not-an-answer, hyperlinks

As you know, diamond moderators can convert answers to comments when necessary. Here is how the banner *(that appears over such deleted answers)* looks like:

> **This answer is hidden**. This answer was [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and converted to a comment X days ago by [Specific Moderator ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

What I'm wondering is why the *"comment"* part of the banner isn't a hyperlink.

When this happens on a really active Meta post, wouldn't it be a small hassle to click on the *"View more comments"* button on the question and/or answers to find the comment that used to be an answer *(to, for example, reply to it)*?

Comment: For starters, it's a comment, it can be deleted and then you just have a useless link. Second, how often does it really happen (ahem, rene)? Especially on Meta

Comment: @Tomerikoo what am I, The Oracle?

Comment: @rene Seems like it... You got notified without the ping xD

Comment: @Tomerikoo I believe deleted posts aren't tracked by SEDE, so it may not be possible to find it out through the public SEDE (but ask rene, I know nothing).

Comment: I don't really see a downside to this, so why not. I might help 10kers while the comment lives and mods forever, and should not hurt anyone. Unless it's hard to implement or support, in which case there would be more important things to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

As users, I don't think anyone would have a good reason to reject this. It surely doesn't hurt anyone if it gets implemented.

Users with less than 10k are not even affected by this. The rest (10kers and mods) can only benefit.

The question is, of course, if it is worth the dev-time. I guess it will be ranked lower on the priority list (as we don't need it *right now*), so we can only hope it will get some attention.